# If A is a positive linear transformation, AB is self-adjoint, then $|(ABx,x)| \leq ||B||(Ax,x)$ or $|(ABx,x)| \leq \rho(B)(Ax,x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Prove or disprove: If $A$ is a positive linear transformation, $AB$ is self-adjoint, then

a, $|(ABx,x)| \leq ||B||.(Ax,x)$

b, $|(ABx,x)| \leq \rho(B).(Ax,x)$

With the matrix norm defined by: $||A|| := \sup_{x \in V}{\frac{||Ax||}{||x||}} = \sup_{x \in V}{\frac{|(Ax,y)|}{||x||.||y||}}.$ If $A$ is self-adjoint, then $||A||$ is also $\sup_{x \in V}{\frac{(Ax,x)}{||x||^2}}$.

And $\rho(B)$ is the spectral radius of linear transformation $B$.

Also, if $A$ is a positive transformation, that means $A = C^{*}C$ for some $C$, or $A = B^2$ for some self-adjoint $B$, or $(Ax,x) \geq 0 \space, \forall x \in V$ and $A$ be self-adjoint. These definitions are equivalent.

The hypothesis "$AB$ is self-adjoint" implys $B$ can be written in the form $CA$, with $C$ be a self-adjoint transformation. But from here, after trying a lot of things, I can't seem to get to that $||B||$. One of the closest results I've got is LHS $\leq ||\sqrt{A}C\sqrt{A}||.(Ax,x)$

Comment: If $AB$ is self adjoint then $AB=B^*A.$

Comment: Yeah, and that. I used that too but can't seem to reach at anything $\leq ||B||(Ax,x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption $AB$ is self-adjoint is equivalent to
$AB=B^*A.$ Thus $AB^k=(B^k)^*A.$ For a positive operator $A$ there holds an analog of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, namely
$$|\langle Ax,y\rangle|\le \langle Ax,x\rangle^{1/2}\langle Ay,y\rangle^{1/2}$$ For $k\ge 1$ we have
$$|\langle AB^kx,x\rangle| =|\langle B^kx,Ax\rangle |\le \langle Ax,x\rangle^{1/2}\langle AB^kx,B^kx\rangle^{1/2}\\
=\langle Ax,x\rangle^{1/2} \langle (B^k)^*AB^kx,x\rangle^{1/2} =
\langle Ax,x\rangle^{1/2}\langle AB^{2k}x,x\rangle^{1/2} $$
Thus
$$ |\langle AB^{2^n}x,x\rangle |\le \langle Ax,x\rangle^{1/2}|\langle AB^{2^{n+1}}x,x\rangle |^{1/2} $$
By iteration we get
$$|\langle ABx,x\rangle |\le \langle Ax,x\rangle^{{1\over 2}+{1\over 4}+\ldots +{1\over 2^{n-1}}}\langle AB^{2^{n}}x,x\rangle ^{1\over 2^n}\\ \le \langle Ax,x\rangle^{1-{1\over 2^n}}\|A\|^{1\over 2^n}\|B^{2^n}\|^{1\over 2^n}\|x\|^{1\over 2^{n-1}}$$
Taking the limit gives
$$|\langle Ax,Bx\rangle |\le \rho(B)\langle Ax,x\rangle$$

Comment: Oh, nice! Thank you!